# Node.js and JSON

Tags: php, javascript, node.js

I am new to node.js so please bear with me.

Here is my situation:

I have a URL that returns JSON.  I need to take this JSON and pass it to a javascript function that returns a custom template.  Currently I am using php to handle the request from the client.  I'm not sure what the best approach is here.  I've tried passing the URL as an argument to the .js program.  I've also tried passing the JSON as an argument but that didn't work at all.  I'm using shell_exec to call the node script.  I'm able to write simple lines of text and they act the way I am expecting.

1. I know this is not the best approach, another solution?
2. How do I pass JSON and parse it as an argument?
3. How do I get the contents from the URL using javascript?

### PHP Code

```
$json = "{'a':'1','b':'2'}";
$test = shell_exec("node example.js ".$json);
```

### Example.js

```
var data = String(process.argv.splice(2));
console.log(data);
```

Comment: Many of the advantages of using Node.js (speed, for the most part) goes right out the window when you've got PHP in front of it, taking the connections. And it's damn slow to spawn new Node processes each time; Node is not made for that.

Comment: Would it be acceptable for you to not involve PHP at all, and have Node take the connection directly? Because then the problem is very easily solvable by much more efficient means than spawning Node processes.

Comment: I suppose so.  I'm just using the PHP at this point to simulate a proof of concept for someone.

Answer (score 4):

Since spaces and quotes have special meaning in command lines, you must [escape](http://php.net/escapeshellarg) them in php. Also note that JSON strings **must** be delimited by double quotes. If you are not a 100% sure about how valid JSON is generated, you should use the [`json_encode`](http://php.net/json_encode) function:

```
<?php
$json = '{"a":"1","b":"2"}';
// or, better:
$json = json_encode(array("a"=>"1", "b"=>"2"));
$test = shell_exec("node example.js ". escapeshellarg($json));
echo $test;
```

Also, your node.js code doesn't actually parse JSON, and converts an array into a string for no good reason. Instead, you want:

```
var data = JSON.parse(process.argv[2]);
console.log(data);
```